# how to update packages inside node_modules

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-update

how to update packages which are in my node_modules but not in dependencies?
I try `npm install --sace --legacy-peer-deps <package-name>` but it add package to my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

maybe in packages.json in the modules what you want to modify and in don't forget to modify in`/ngx/package.json` too. And don't forget to delete your package.json.lock after each manipulations.